# Help understanding proof of The Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation, induction, cyclic-groups

In Hungerford's *Abstract Algebra: An Introduction*, he writes The Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Groups as:

> "Every finite abelian group G is the direct sum of cyclic groups, each of prime power order.

The following is the proof for this theorem:
[image]

My problem is that I do not understand the inductive proof - where is the inductive step? The basis step is that the assertion is true when $H$ has order $2$, which was shown previously in the book, but it looks like they just take the induction step for granted.

Comment: He does strong induction, because he sais that assume inductively that it is tru for all groups whose order is less than $|H|$. So if you take $K$ such as $H=<a> \bigoplus K$ then $|K|<|H|$, so you can use the inductive hypothesis. By the way i don't like that proof so much, i recommend you the one in the book "José F. Fernando, J. Manuel Gamboa; Estructuras algebraicas"

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text.

Comment: Honestly, I do not understand why someone would downvote this question just for having used a screenshot. Could someone explain why it is *never* acceptable to use a screenshot? Seems a bit strange in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When he takes an element $a$ of maximal order and writes $H = \langle a \rangle \oplus K$, since the order of $a$ is greater than $1$, the order of $K$ is less than the order of $H$. Moreover, $K$ is a $p$-group, because it is a subgroup of a $p$-group.

The induction hypothesis is “for every $p$-group of order less than $\mid H \mid$, that $p$-group is the direct sum of cyclic groups.”

This means that $K$ is a group that satisfies the induction hypothesis, and this is where it is used.

I also consider the proof a bit odd, and would probably fix an arbitrary prime $p$ beforehand, and do an induction on the exponent of that prime. The proof would then go by exactly the same.

Comment: Just to be clear: the inductive step is that if it is true for all p-groups of order less than $H$, then it is also true for $H$?

Comment: @Logi Precisely!

Comment: Great, thank you!